# this' attributes don't get detected in x-on:click

Tags: alpine.js

This works :

```
<input
id="chk-products"
name="chk-products"
type="checkbox"
x-on:click="showProducts = document.getElementById('chk-products').checked">
```

But this doesn't :

```
<input
id="chk-products"
name="chk-products"
type="checkbox"
x-on:click="showProducts = this.checked">
```

I was wondering why `this` isn't available in alpinejs's directives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Alpine.js you don't have to inspect/mutate the DOM manually. It uses the [data model](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data): first you define some data, then you bind it to some input elements and let Alpine.js handle the DOM mutations, etc.

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{showProducts: false}">
  <input type="checkbox" x-model="showProducts" /> Show products
  <div x-show="showProducts">Products are shown.</div>
  <div x-show="!showProducts">Products are hidden.</div>
</div>
```

The `this` keyword is available inside a component created with [`Alpine.data()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) global function.

Answer (score 1):

The `x-on:click` directive in `Alpine.js` is designed to execute a JavaScript expression when an element is clicked. In this case, the expression is trying to access the checked state of the checkbox element, which can be done more directly by using the `this` keyword to access the element that the directive is applied to. Unfortunately, `Alpine.js` does not support the use of the this keyword in its directives.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat old question, but this here should work perfectly:

```
<input
id="chk-products"
name="chk-products"
type="checkbox"
x-on:click="showProducts = $el.checked">
```

The [$el magic property](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/el) should select that element.